# Rust: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust

Minimal reproducible code:

```rust
trait VecExt<T, R> {
    fn map(&self, f: impl Fn(&T) -> R) -> Vec<R>;
}

impl<T, R> VecExt<T, R> for Vec<T> {
    fn map(&self, f: impl Fn(&T) -> R) -> Vec<R> {
        self.iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}

struct A {
    a: Vec<Option<String>>
}

impl A {
    fn foo(&self) -> Vec<Option<&String>> {
        self.a.map(|o| o.as_ref())
    }
}
```

Getting error message:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
```

When using `self.a.iter().map(|o| o.as_ref()).collect()`, it compiles.

I've already read the explain document, but I still don't know why this error occurs and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `map` call in `A.foo` is replaced with the code from the `map` function, it compiles, which indicates that the issue is with the trait definition not constraining the lifetime of the argument passed to the closure.

In the case of `fn map(&self, f: impl Fn(&T) -> R) -> Vec<R>`, the lifetime of the reference passed as `&T` in `impl Fn(&T) -> R` must live for at least as long as the `&self` argument passed into it.  The following changes should make it compile

```
trait VecExt<'a, T, R> where T: 'a {
    fn map(&'a self, f: impl Fn(&'a T) -> R) -> Vec<R>;
}

impl<'a, T, R> VecExt<'a, T, R> for Vec<T> where T: 'a {
    fn map(&'a self, f: impl Fn(&'a T) -> R) -> Vec<R> {
        self.iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}
```